# Characters are converted in special symbols

Tags: database, excel, sqlite, special-characters

I have database records available in MSExcel file. I save it as CSV file. And then create database in firefox's SQLiteManager by importing that CSV file .

But the characters like ..., ' , ",- are converted in �.

I have also tried to save CSV file in UTF-8 formate, but it converts that characters in Õ

Has anyone idea , how to solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you might want to consider escaping quotes, e.g. try "" or "' in your csv file. And just pay a bit more attention to **Fields enclosed by** section in SQLiteManager add-on, making sure these fields are enclosed properly.